Noncommutative conditional Hölder inequality
Does there exist a noncommutative version of the conditional Hölder inequality? I'm thinking of a statement along the lines of: Let $M$ be a finite von Neumann algebra with normal tracial faithful state $\tau: M \rightarrow \mathbb C$ and $E: M \rightarrow N$ a conditional expectation onto a von Neumann subalgebra $N \subset M$. Do we have an inequality of the form
$$
\tau(E(\lvert xy \rvert)) \leq \tau(E(\lvert x \rvert^p))^{1/p} \tau(E(\lvert y \rvert)^q)^{1/q}
$$
for $p, q \geq 1$ with $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$ and $x,y \in M$?

Usually, if you have a subalgebra of a tracial von Neumann algebra, the conditional expectation would be the unique trace-preserving one, in which case $\tau \circ E$ is just $\tau$ and this is the usual non-commutative Hölder inequality. Do you specifically want the conditional expectation to not be trace-preserving or something?

If that is the case, then this is not even true for $N = \mathbb{C}$ - since in that case $\tau \circ E$ is just an arbitrary state and it is known that the noncommutative Hölder inequality fails for states in general.

Hm, I see. The situation I really care about is the following: $M$ is finite-dimensional and $E$ is a compression by some projection $p$. So what I actually would like to have is an inequality of the form $\tau(p \lvert x y \rvert p) \leq \tau(p \lvert x \rvert^2 p)^{1/2} \tau(p \lvert y \rvert^2 p)^{1/2}$.

This is false even in $2 \times 2$ matrices. Just take $x = e_{12}$, $y = e_{21}$, $p = e_{11}$, say.

That's a pity. Thanks anyways.
